# Need help populating 2 form fields using a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, populate

I have a form with 2 input fields. With the click of a link I would like to populate these 2 form fields. I posted on jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/6AMNb/9/ ) what I have so far but I believe my syntax is incorrect somewhere.  Any help would be HUGELY appreciated!  Thanks, Mitch

Comment: What does `.populate()` do? Your jsfiddle does not include the plugin, you can add it by clicking on "Add Resources" and pasting in the location of the plugin.

Comment: ...
http://jsfiddle.net/6AMNb/13/

Answer (score 1):

`.populate()` is not a default method of jQuery. You need to include the [Populate plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Populate).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of populating the form inputs: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/6AMNb/12/

I added the following code to your click handler for the `.AddCart` link.

```
$('#QOCode').val('ML10854');
$('#QOQty').val('1');
```

**--UPDATE--**

I changed the code to increment the quantity on subsequent clicks of the `.AddCart` link: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/6AMNb/14/

Comment: @maxedison That's Mitch Causin's code that I updated; I do not know the state the of DOM elements on `document.ready` so I did not change it to `.bind()`. I didn't change it to `.on()`/`.delegate()` because I am unaware of the actual DOM structure so delegating the event handler could cause problems.